# start service from asp.net core web application

Tags: asp.net-core

I am Building web application on asp.net core.
my application needs some data once in a week.

I have created console application which gets this data (really, it parses some website once in a week and stores that data in a database).

I have configuration file when should that console application start to get that data.

My question is how to start that console application from my web app and is it a good idea to start console application from web application?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's not best practice to start a console application from an web application. If you would like to do that, please consider using a Windows Service with an timer or a cron job for that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a scheduled tasks using Windows Task Scheduler. This task's action will be to `State a Program` and then you can set Program/Script to your console exe file. You can schedule this task to run once a week.

You can check this task history to ensure the task is executing weekly and can run it manually in case of failure.

[image]